# Cannot read input file ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to read an input file formatted with two numbers on a line and store the first number in the line in one vector and the second number in another vector.

Every part of my code works fine except for the actual *reading of the file*.

I have put `couts` all over the place and it looks like while my file is being opened, it's not being read, so my vectors keep getting filled until I run out of memory.

Here's the part of my code that reads the file:

```
cout << "Input Filename: ";
cin >> input;
//open input file
inputdata.open(input.c_str());
if(!inputdata){
cerr << "Error: Unable to open file!" << endl;
}

while(!inputdata.eof()){
    counter++;
    hold = 0;
    if(counter > 0){
        inputdata >> hold;
        //cout << hold << endl;
        if(counter%2 != 0)
            data.push_back(hold);
        else
            weight.push_back(hold);
    }
}
```

(where counter is an integer initialized at -1 since there is a one-word title at the beginning of the input file that I need to ignore).

I know using `.eof()` is frowned upon, but it won't actually affect what I'm doing.

Does anyone see a problem in my code or why it wouldn't be reading the file?

Comment: Please post more code prior to the while loop.

Comment: Don't rely on eof. It is probably that hold is reading -1 ( which is actually an EOF) but it isn't setting the eof bit, it happens with formatted i/o on file. Either add if ( holder == -1) break; or better yet try to use get to read the file.( using get will make the eof work).

Comment: Try testing `inputdata` instead of `!inputdata.eof()`. That would also test for problems other than eof.

Comment: @ 0A0D done @xeon I tried couting inputdata but it just returns 0 every time

Comment: @Will wait you said one word title , with emphasis on the word part. use a string to read the word, your input is failing there, you are trying to input a word while the input expected is int.

Comment: We can't decide what's going wrong, when we do not know the variable types. So please add their definition.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice) for why it is a bad idea to have an input loop check for EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
std::string firstword;
inputdata >> firstword; // or std::getline(inputdate, firstword);

while (inputdata >> w >> d)
{
  weight.push_back(w);
  data.push_back(d);
}
```

It's much cleaner since data and weight go in pairs (maybe I changed w and d).

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to use `.eof()` in a while loop. For example,

```
while(!inputdata.eof()){
   ... 
}
```

*Wrong*.

This is the [correct use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice).

```
if (!(cin >> foo)) {
  if (cin.eof()) {
    cout << "read failed due to EOF\n";
  } else {
    cout << "read failed due to something other than EOF\n";
  }
}
```

Additionally, at the [C++ FAQ, in Section 15.5](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5) it says "Why does my input seem process past the end of a file?"

> Because the eof state may not get set until after a read is attempted
>   past the end of file. That is, reading the last byte from a file might
>   not set the eof state. E.g., suppose the input stream is mapped to a
>   keyboard — in that case it's not even theoretically possible for the
>   C++ library to predict whether or not the character that the user just
>   typed will be the last character.

You also need to check if your `fstream` is properly open by doing this,

```
if (inputdata.is_open()) { /* ok, proceed with output */ }
```

Doing `if(!inputdata)` is not the proper check.

Answer (score 0):

"since there is a one-word title at the beginning of the input file that I need to ignore"
That might be problematic. Trying to read a text with ints or floats is asking for trouble.

If this word is on a seperate line, try this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Else, try to read the first word with a temporary string.\