# c++ read from stdin store in vector and stdout

Tags: c++, linux

i am testing out this code which reads stdin and stores it in vector and stdout..any idea what the problem could be??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string> vs;
  vector<string>::iterator vsi;

  string buffer;
  while (!(cin.eof())) {
    getline(cin, buffer);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    vs.push_back(buffer);
  };

  for (int count=1 , vsi = vs.begin(); vsi != vs.end(); vsi++,count++){
    cout << "string" << count <<"="<< *vsi << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}



[root@server dev]# g++ -o newcode newcode.cpp 
newcode.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
newcode.cpp:19: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
newcode.cpp:19: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘vsi != vs.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]()’
newcode.cpp:20: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
[root@server dev]#
```

Comment: Note: The `while` loop is fundamentally broken. Never do `while (!(cin.eof())) { ` ( you can find many articles on SO about it have a search. You should be doing `while(getline(cin, buffer)) {`

Comment: Quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7858319/14065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the initialization part of the `for` loop, you declare a new variable `vsi` whose type is `int`.

One way to fix the problem:

```
vsi = vs.begin();
for (int count=1; vsi != vs.end(); ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is on this line:

```
for (int count=1 , vsi = vs.begin(); vsi != vs.end(); vsi++,count++)
```

You define two `int` variables: `count` and `vsi`. Then, you try to assign the second with `vs.begin()`. This is what the compiler complains about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that vs.begin() does not return an int, and you declared vsi as an integer.

Easy fix:

```
for (int count=0;count < vs.size(); ++count){
  cout << "string" << (count+1) <<"="<< vs[count] << endl;
}
```

Notes:

- prefer `++count` to `count++`
  Though it makes not difference in this case there are situations where it does.
  So it is a good habit to get into.
  See: [Performance difference between ++iterator and iterator++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303899/14065)
- `while (!(cin.eof()))` is practically always wrong (in all languages).
  The 'eof flag' is not set to true until after you read past the eof.
  The last successful read reads up-to (but not past) the eof. So you enter the loop a final time and the read will fail yet you still push back a value into the vector.

  - In Some situations this can cause an infinite loop.
    If there is another type of failure on read you will never reach the eof
    (eg cin >> x; Where x is an int may fail if input is not an integer)
    See: [c++ reading undefined number of lines with eof()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7858319/14065)