# c++ sscanf reading string vector

Tags: c++, linux

thanks for the support on the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934436/c-read-from-stdin-store-in-vector-and-stdout)... i am now trying to store the vector string on another string and do a sscanf to check for a text eg. "TEXT" and if found append another text at the end of line....

any ideas???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string> vs;
  vector<string>::iterator vsi;
  string agent;
  string buffer;
  string line;
  while (!(cin.eof())) {
    getline(cin, buffer);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    vs.push_back(buffer);
  };

  vsi = vs.begin();
  for (int count=1; vsi != vs.end(); vsi++,count++){
    cout << "string" << count <<"="<< *vsi << endl;
    line = *vsi;
    sscanf(line, "%s %[^\n]",text);
//dummy code
if text=="TEXT" do this:
    cout << "agent" << text << "endl";
  }
else: do nothing


  return 0;
}



[root@server dev]# g++ -o newcode newcode.cpp 
newcode.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
newcode.cpp:24: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int sscanf(const char*, const char*, ...)’
[root@server dev]#
```

UPDATE:
i used line.c_str() on sscanf and gives out this error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<string> vs;
  vector<string>::iterator vsi;
  string agent;
  string buffer;
  string line;
  while (!(cin.eof())) {
    getline(cin, buffer);
    cout << buffer << endl;
    vs.push_back(buffer);
  };

  vsi = vs.begin();
  for (int count=1; vsi != vs.end(); vsi++,count++){
    cout << "string" << count <<"="<< *vsi << endl;
    line = *vsi;
    cout << "LINE:" << line.c_str() << endl;
    sscanf(line.c_str(), "%s %[^\n]",agent);
 /*   cout << "agent" << agent << "endl"; */
  }

  return 0;
}

[root@server dev]# g++ -o newcode newcode.cpp 
newcode.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
newcode.cpp:25: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct std::string’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
[root@server dev]#
```

what i want to do is when a string on a particular line is detected it will append a text to the end of line and stdout...

Comment: I see you have edited the question, can you put a comment with the line number that the error is occurring on. Something like `\\this is line 25` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do but if you want to get the right type passed into sscanf you'll need to change some things around. `sscanf` only deals with c strings and you've tried to pass it in a c++ string object, to fix this you might want to use `line.c_str()` in sscanf to get it passed in the right format.

A better approach would be to use a c++ algorithm like string::find though as this will remove the need to use sscanf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of you want to do, but you should check out string::find : [Cplusplus reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sscanf` try using `stringstream` which work nearly the same as `cin`/`cout`.