# How can i read first line from file?

Tags: c++

```
ifstream infile;

string read_file_name("test.txt");

infile.open(read_file_name);

string sLine;

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        getline(infile, sLine);         
        cout << sLine.data() << endl;
    }

    infile.close();
```

This program prints all line in the file, but I want to print only first line.

Comment: just get rid of while loop and `while (!infile.eof())` isn't correct anyway

Comment: Why would you expect a loop to only go through once (unless the condition is set up that way)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`while (!infile.eof())` does not work as you expected, [eof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) see one useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice/5837668#5837668)

Minor fix to your code, should work:

```
  ifstream infile("test.txt");

  if (infile.good())
  {
    string sLine;
    getline(infile, sLine);
    cout << sLine << endl;
  }
```

Comment: No need to call `close` as destructor will do that for you

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ifstream infile;

string read_file_name("test.txt");

infile.open(read_file_name);

string sLine;

while (!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> sLine;
    cout << sLine.data() << endl;

}

infile.close();
```

This should print all the lines in your file, line by line.