# Issue with finding the end of a file?

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop, infinite-loop, eof

having an issue reading input from a file, counting the amount of characters in each word, then outputting this count to an output file.

example content in input file:
one two three four five

correct output would be:
3 3 5 4 4

Now the code below works if in the input file I put a blank space at the end of 'five'.  If i don't put this empty space, the code gets stuck in the embedded while loop (see below).

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c; //declare variable c of type char
    int count = 0; //declar variable count of type int and initializes to 0
    ifstream infile( "input.txt" ); //opens file input.txt for reading
    ofstream outfile( "output.txt" ); //opens file output.txt for writing

    c = infile.get(); //gets first character from infile and assigns to variable c

    //while the end of file is not reached
    while ( !infile.eof() )
    {
        //while loop that counts the number of characters until a space is found
        while( c != ' ' ) //THIS IS THE WHILE LOOP WHERE IT GETS STUCK
        {
            count++; //increments counter
            c = infile.get(); //gets next character
        }

        c = infile.get(); //gets next character

        outfile << count << " "; //writes space to output.txt
        count = 0; //reset counter
    }

    //closes files
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while ( !infile.eof() )` no no no no

Comment: Excuse ignorance - but what do you say 'no no no no' for !infile.eof().  Just looking to expand my understanding.

Comment: @miltonb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice

Comment: Thanks @user657267. My code must now change, immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of solving this is to simplify:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string word;
  std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
  std::ofstream outfile("output.txt");

  while (infile >> word)
    outfile << word.size() << ' ';
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked great!  much simpler way of getting to where i needed to go.  i need to KISS in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the condition of the inner while:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c; //declare variable c of type char
    int count = 0; //declar variable count of type int and initializes to 0
    ifstream infile( "input.txt" ); //opens file input.txt for reading
    ofstream outfile( "output.txt" ); //opens file output.txt for writing

    c = infile.get(); //gets first character from infile and assigns to variable c

    //while the end of file is not reached
    while ( !infile.eof() )
    {
        //while loop that counts the number of characters until a space is found
        while( c != ' ' &&  !infile.eof() )
        {
            count++; //increments counter
            c = infile.get(); //gets next character
        }

        c = infile.get(); //gets next character

        outfile << count << " "; //writes space to output.txt
        count = 0; //reset counter
    }

    //closes files
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Check EOF by checking characters as:

`while(fgetc(infile) != EOF){
//Rest code goes here
}`