# Reading a csv file and store the values in c++

Tags: c++, csv

I have a csv file with the pattern:

```
firstname, lastname, id
angelina, jolie, 247 
... and so on...
```

I want to store the values in a `Student` class, but the problem is that it takes the last word of the first line and it concatenate with the first word of the second line(`idangelina`).The list has 5000 students to store in a `Student` array and I don't know how to separate them.
The function is this:

```
int readFromCsv(string filePath, Student v[]){
    string line;
    ifstream csvfile;
    csvfile.open(filePath);
    int i = 0;
    while ( !csvfile.eof() ){//loops until the end of the file
        getline(csvfile, line, ',');//read a string until the next comma
        v[i].setFirstName(line); //set each student
        getline(csvfile, line, ',');
        v[i].setLastName(line);
        getline(csvfile, line, ',');
        v[i].setId(line);
        i += 1;
    }
    csvfile.close();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector`, you need to pass the size of `v` so that the code won't go out of bounds.

Comment: I am using i to return the size of the array, knowing that each line represents a student.The problem is how to separate the student id with the next name.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047052/why-does-reading-a-struct-record-fields-from-stdistream-fail-and-how-can-i-fi

Comment: @EugenEugen no, you are returning how many elements *you've written values to*, not the size of the array. The caller determines how big `v` is, and the file could have more than the caller has allocated! This is why we use `std::vector`.

Comment: You can see complete examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c.

Comment: See also: [why eof is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

For the last field in one line you should use

```
getline(csvfile, line);
v[i].setId(line);
```

instead of

```
getline(csvfile, line, ',');
v[i].setId(line);
```

because for the last field you don't want to read until the next comma but until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

`,` does not separate one record's ID from the next record's first name, so you cannot use it as a delimiter for that column.

Also you need to put a limit on how many records you can read, otherwise you risk overrunning `v` if the file has too many records.