# read from file to string and pass to function

Tags: c++

I am having some issues trying to understand why I am getting a Exception thrown to this section when I am trying to pass a string that contains content from a getline() statement.

```
`reference operator[](const size_type _Off)
{   // subscript mutable sequence
auto& _My_data = this->_Get_data();
_IDL_VERIFY(_Off <= _My_data._Mysize, "string subscript out of range");
return (_My_data._Myptr()[_Off]);
}`

void set_token(string n);
    string token;

        while (fin.peek() != '0' && !fin.eof())
        {
            getline(fin, token);
            set_token(token);
        }

`void set_token(string n)
{
    string strarray[20];
    string token;
    int size = sizeof(n);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        if (n[i] != ' ' && n[i] != '\0')
        {
            token += n[i];
        }
        else
        {
            strarray[j] = token;
            j++;
            token.clear();
            lexical(strarray[j]);
        }
        i++;
    }`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice

Comment: you haven't shown us the `set_token` function!!!

Comment: @john it crashes before even executing a command in the `set_token` function.

Comment: So where is the exception thrown? And which exception is thrown?

Comment: Does it crash the first time round the loop, or after the first time round the loop?

Comment: @AchimGuetlein I'm guessing "string subscript out of range". It seems very likely that the bug is in `set_token` but we have to persuade the OP of this.

Comment: `int size = sizeof(n);` super broken.

Comment: @john I have added the set_token. It crashes first time round the loop.

Comment: @Nignig are you sure? This is a clear bug `int size = sizeof(n);`, should be `int size = n.size();`, `sizeof` does something else.

Comment: @melpomene Ok this seems to fix the problem weirdly. Thanks

Comment: @Nignig Often given advice is to use a debugger for this kind of problem. It would have found the problem very quickly

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see any problem in getline() but in set_token() there is obvious run-time issue when you extract the size of n. The sizeof doesn’t give you total number of characters in string but size() does.

Try this:
    size = n.size():