# Ignoring whitespace in string stream doesn't work with skipws flag

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I am trying to solve a problem that evaluates simple expressions in a string like `10+20` should return `30`

The problem is the string can contain white spaces so i uses `stringstring` with `skipws` flag it works for white spaces within the string like `10 + 20` etc but when white space is in the end its not passing towards the correctly.

This is how I am parsing the string

```
void build_stack(const string& str) {
    istringstream ss(str);

    char op;
    int op1, op2;
    ss>>skipws>>op1;
    operands.push(op1);
    while(!ss.eof()) {
        ss>>op;
        operators.push(op);
        ss>>op2;
        operands.push(op2);
    }
}
```

full code with various string inputs [here in rextester](https://rextester.com/FBZN42201).

when the string is `3+5 / 2` my stacks gets built as 
`operands => 2 2 5 3`
`operators => / / +`

when the string is `3+5 / 2` (i.e with trailing whitespace) my stacks gets built as 
`operands => 2 5 3`
`operators => / +`

i tried

```
while(ss.peek() == ' ') {
    char c; ss>>c;
}
```

but this is removing all characters after seeing a whitespace.

Comment: Always test all input operations,  such as use of operator >>, and report failures. And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Don't do `while(!ss.eof())` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837639/eof-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Example `"3+5 / 2 "`:

1. `ss>>skipws>>op1;`

   3 is written into `op1`
2. `operands.push(op1);`

   `op1` is pushed into `operands`
3. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

   is true
4. `ss>>op;`

   `+` is written into `op`
5. `operators.push(op);`

   `op` is pushed into `operators`
6. `ss>>op2;`

   `5` is written into `op2`
7. `operands.push(op2);`

   `op2` is pushed into `operands`
8. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

   is true
9. `ss>>op;`

   `/` is written into `op`
10. `operators.push(op);`

    `op` is pushed into `operators`
11. `ss>>op2;`

    `2` is written into `op2`
12. `operands.push(op2);`

    `op2` is pushed into `operands`, `ss` contains a whitespace, not empty
13. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

    is true
14. `ss>>op;`

    can't be read, `/` stays in `op`, eof is set
15. `operators.push(op);`

    `op` is pushed into `operators`
16. `ss>>op2;`

    can't be read, `2` stays in `op2`
17. `operands.push(op2);`

    `op2` is pushed into `operands`
18. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

    is false

in contrast to example `"3+5 / 2"`:

1. `ss>>skipws>>op1;`

   3 is written into `op1`
2. `operands.push(op1);`

   `op1` is pushed into `operands`
3. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

   is true
4. `ss>>op;`

   `+` is written into `op`
5. `operators.push(op);`

   `op` is pushed into `operators`
6. `ss>>op2;`

   `5` is written into `op2`
7. `operands.push(op2);`

   `op2` is pushed into `operands`
8. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

   is true
9. `ss>>op;`

   `/` is written into `op`
10. `operators.push(op);`

    `op` is pushed into `operators`
11. `ss>>op2;`

    `2` is written into `op2`
12. `operands.push(op2);`

    `op2` is pushed into `operands`, `ss` is empty, eof is set
13. `while(!ss.eof()) {`

    is false

You can fix it with

```
void build_stack(const string& str) {
    istringstream ss(str);

    char op;
    int op1, op2;
    ss>>skipws>>op1;
    operands.push(op1);
    while(true) {
        if (!(ss>>op)) break;
        operators.push(op);
        if (!(ss>>op2)) break;
        operands.push(op2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik for the step by step explanation. So the value is being reused from the stack confirmed by modifying the values in the stack and see the dummy values gets inserted new source [location](https://rextester.com/MQQJ44129).

My question still is since the ignore whitespace flag is set shouldnt `ss.eof()` check right away if remaining stream is valid or the last read adjust whitespace characters ?

Rightnow i switched to `while(ss>>op)` instead. to avoid two breaks.

Comment: First, `ss>>skipws` does nothing in your example. skipws is the default behavior: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws. Whitespaces are skipped until input, not after input. "_Enables or disables skipping of __leading__ whitespace"_ Without both breaks input like `5+5+` will yield `5 5 5` and `+ +`.